# Access home folder in external hard drive

Tags: permissions, opensuse, external-hdd, cloning

I recently changed from an HDD to SSD on my machine. The HDD had a dual boot with Windows and openSUSE. The Windows system had no password, the openSUSE had a password.

When putting the HDD in an enclosure and opening on my machine (with the SSD), it can read the Windows partition fine. However for the openSUSE partition, the home folder comes up empty, despite  Dolphin indicating it has the same amount of free space as it had when it was still the drive being used on my machine - indicating the home folder does have files.

How can I access these files/change permissions on the drive to allow the files to be viewable?

Edit: Added the below screenshot for more context. The home folder here, comes up empty
[image]

Edit 3: Removed screenshot of etc/fstab and replaced with text

```
UUID=fc0c9294-3280-4ba0-a961-f4e451b74d16  /                       btrfs  defaults                      0  0
UUID=fc0c9294-3280-4ba0-a961-f4e451b74d16  /.snapshots             btrfs  subvol=/@/.snapshots          0  0
UUID=bd5f56cc-2ccb-4ee1-beb0-a0451f831849  swap                    swap   defaults                      0  0
UUID=fc0c9294-3280-4ba0-a961-f4e451b74d16  /var                    btrfs  subvol=/@/var                 0  0
UUID=fc0c9294-3280-4ba0-a961-f4e451b74d16  /usr/local              btrfs  subvol=/@/usr/local           0  0
UUID=fc0c9294-3280-4ba0-a961-f4e451b74d16  /srv                    btrfs  subvol=/@/srv                 0  0
UUID=fc0c9294-3280-4ba0-a961-f4e451b74d16  /root                   btrfs  subvol=/@/root                0  0
UUID=fc0c9294-3280-4ba0-a961-f4e451b74d16  /opt                    btrfs  subvol=/@/opt                 0  0
UUID=fc0c9294-3280-4ba0-a961-f4e451b74d16  /home                   btrfs  subvol=/@/home                0  0
UUID=fc0c9294-3280-4ba0-a961-f4e451b74d16  /boot/grub2/x86_64-efi  btrfs  subvol=/@/boot/grub2/x86_64-efi  0  0
UUID=fc0c9294-3280-4ba0-a961-f4e451b74d16  /boot/grub2/i386-pc     btrfs  subvol=/@/boot/grub2/i386-pc  0  0
UUID=DD84-65A8                             /boot/efi               vfat   utf8                          0  2
```

Below is output for my own /etc/fstab. I noticed the /home directories have a different filesystem.

```
UUID=42930651-6638-4016-8321-b911f3a8d992  /                       btrfs  defaults                      0  0
UUID=42930651-6638-4016-8321-b911f3a8d992  /var                    btrfs  subvol=/@/var                 0  0
UUID=42930651-6638-4016-8321-b911f3a8d992  /usr/local              btrfs  subvol=/@/usr/local           0  0
UUID=42930651-6638-4016-8321-b911f3a8d992  /srv                    btrfs  subvol=/@/srv                 0  0
UUID=42930651-6638-4016-8321-b911f3a8d992  /root                   btrfs  subvol=/@/root                0  0
UUID=42930651-6638-4016-8321-b911f3a8d992  /opt                    btrfs  subvol=/@/opt                 0  0
UUID=42930651-6638-4016-8321-b911f3a8d992  /boot/grub2/x86_64-efi  btrfs  subvol=/@/boot/grub2/x86_64-efi  0  0
UUID=42930651-6638-4016-8321-b911f3a8d992  /boot/grub2/i386-pc     btrfs  subvol=/@/boot/grub2/i386-pc  0  0
UUID=42930651-6638-4016-8321-b911f3a8d992  /.snapshots             btrfs  subvol=/@/.snapshots          0  0
UUID=771834db-7510-48b3-ae19-5652abba6cae  /home                   ext4   data=ordered                  0  2
UUID=40132844-1f71-41fd-9b21-6f2919afafbd  swap                    swap   defaults                      0  0
UUID=4149-F793                             /boot/efi               vfat   utf8                          0  2
```

The output of ls /media/siya/fc0c9294-3280-4ba0-a961-f4e451b74d16/home:

```
ls: cannot access '/media/siya/fc0c9294-3280-4ba0-a961-f4e451b74d16/home': No such file or directory
```

Comment: look in the /etc/fstab on your hard drive. I bet /home is on a different volume than the one you're currently looking at!

Comment: I added a screenshot for more context. I dont understand your answer.

Comment: @siya On the HDD, please search for the file `etc/fstab` and add the contents to your question.

Comment: @FelixJN I've done so.

Comment: @siya - please try not to post screenshots for text files but use [editing](https://unix.stackexchange.com/editing-help). 
Now open a terminal and try to list the contents of the old home via `ls /media/siya/fc0c9294-3280-4ba0-a961-f4e451b74d15/home`. What is the result?

Comment: @FelixJN - sorry for that, I've corrected it. I noticed the last number you typed was incorrect due to it being a screenshot, which is why its different here. output is: ls: cannot access '/media/siya/fc0c9294-3280-4ba0-a961-f4e451b74d16/home': No such file or directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/463086/reading-home-folder-of-old-computer-in-a-new-computer) answer, it seems the issue arose from having different filesystems for my current /home and the old /home. My answer is adapted for mounting a btrfs system on ext4.

Mounting the btrfs system with:

```
sudo mount /dev/sdb6 -o subvol=/@/home /mnt/stuff
```

where

- /dev/sdb6 is obtained from running `lsblk` and selecting the volume with the partition you want:

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
...
sdb      8:16   0 931.5G  0 disk 
├─sdb1   8:17   0   499M  0 part 
├─sdb2   8:18   0    99M  0 part 
├─sdb3   8:19   0    16M  0 part 
├─sdb4   8:20   0 491.5G  0 part 
├─sdb5   8:21   0   512M  0 part 
├─sdb6   8:22   0 339.3G  0 part
...
```

- `subvol=/@/home` is obtained from mounting normally with `mount /dev/sdb6 /mnt/stuff` and copying the subvol expression for the folder in question (here, it's the home folder) from etc/fstab (which is shown in the original question).
- `/mnt/stuff` is a mountpoint on your system.

works.